# How launch Python script from PHP script?

Tags: python, php

I'm trying to launch a script from PHP whith argument i try this file :

PHP page (index.php):

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
        $output = shell_exec('python light.py "11"');
        echo"launch";
        echo $output;   ?>
```

Python script light.py (same folder):

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import syslog
import time
import sys 

param = sys.argv[1]

arduino = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)
time.sleep(2)
arduino.write(bytes(param, 'utf-8'))
time.sleep(2)
```

this is my arduino script, this script send a command to another uno whith the MIRF library, this script works perfectly

```
#include <SPI.h>      
#include <Mirf.h>     
#include <nRF24L01.h> 
#include <MirfHardwareSpiDriver.h> 
int incomingByte = 0;

typedef struct {
  int commande;
  int valeur;
} MaStructure;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Mirf.cePin = 9; 
  Mirf.csnPin = 10; 
  Mirf.spi = &MirfHardwareSpi; 
  Mirf.init(); 
  Mirf.channel = 1; 
  Mirf.payload = sizeof(MaStructure); 
  Mirf.config(); 
  Mirf.setTADDR((byte *) "nrf02"); 
  Mirf.setRADDR((byte *) "nrf01"); 
  Serial.println("Go !"); 
}

void loop() {
  MaStructure message;

    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            incomingByte = Serial.parseInt();

          switch(incomingByte){
                case 10:
                 message.commande = 1;
                 message.valeur = 0;
                 Mirf.send((byte*) &message);
                 while(Mirf.isSending()); 
                 break;
              
                case 11:
                 message.commande = 1;
                 message.valeur = 1;
                 Mirf.send((byte*) &message); 
                 while(Mirf.isSending()); 
                 break;
               }
            }
         }
```

The Python script is working when I launch from the terminal.

And if i launch the php scrit from the terminal like : php index.php all is ok.

So the problem comes from the browser ....

Comment: You should clarify the bit about "the script is launching but not the function". It's not obvious if your python script won't run, or if it's running and erroring.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the Python script you call `sendToSerial(param)` which returns the data that it reads, but you do not print that data anywhere. So I think it just looks like the function did not run. If I put `print(sendToSerial(param))` at the end, it seems to run fine.